# Block IP's that fail to login in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security

I have SQL Server on a server exposed to internet, several clients and servers make connections to access some data, due to technical reasons I can't use VPN.

I know this is very risky. The only thing it came to my mind to lower the risk is to make SQL Server  to listen to a different port other than 1433 (26173), although I know someone could scan ports and find it.

So I'm trying to find out a way to audit failed logins and block remote ip, is there a solution like this?

Comment: This *guarantees* you'll be hacked. To avoid a breach requires a *lot* of work and knowing what you do. At the very least,  use a firewall and allow *only known IPs* to connect.You'll have to do that both at the firewall and *router* level. Use [HTTPS connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) *only*.  [Enable password policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017) which enforces password rules.

Comment: High-end firewalls (ie not Windows Firewall) can inspect packets, understand login/logout attempts, use rules to block IPs. At that point though, you might as well create a proper VPN.

Comment: A better idea would be to redesign the application so clients *don't* connect to the database directly. Create services that talk to the database and have clients connect to those services only.

Comment: Even if I use very strong passwords? like:  j_wU$8-!q_M2#k  What good does it do to make a service talk to SQL Server, they could find the that service and try to talk to it, isn't it?

Comment: That password won't prevent sniffing of the unencrypted communications, username *and* password. It won't even need a lot of work - a fake proxy, DNS spoofing, a hedgehog for WiFi and all client communications will go through the hacker's machine

Comment: Communications are encrypted from point to point using the encryption options in SQL Standard 2017

Comment: Even better than VPN is abstracting the specific DB calls you need to allow into an authenticated web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux I would use fail2ban for this, there seems to be a [windows version](https://github.com/glasnt/wail2ban) you could look into that.

Comment: I know it is a security issue I must resolve in the near future, but for the time being, I think this will do the job

Comment: No, it will definitely *NOT* do. Linux systems don't use such software for security, they use OpenVPN. Those that just use IP banning and unencrypted communications end up in haveibeenpwned

Answer (score 1):

I've created a little software to help with failed sql login attempts, so i can get a notification by email or SMS when it reaches a big number of failed logins and block ip automatically. It's in VB.net but you can easily convert to c#. This is a portion of an application that i use to do several maintenance tasks to a server.

Just create a Project in VB.NET Forms and add a Form. You'll need a DataGridView1 with the columns name: xText, xIp, xSameIp, xAction.
In the datagrid set AllowUsersToAddRows to false.
Create a Label with name lblSQLLOGS_Saved so that the application doesn't read all info if there are not changes in SQL Log.

This application shows line by line the text and the ip of failed logins attempts and an Action to what should be done. It can be simplified but i like to see on a grid what is happening.  I have this routine in a Timer ticking every 30 secs. Remember to activate in your SQL - properties - security - login auditing - (at least) Failed logins only.  Here is the routine:

```
Imports System.IO

Sub CheckSqlLogs()
    Dim sSqlLogPathFile As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.---CHANGE TO YOU REAL INSTANCE NAME----\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG"
 
    '-- To avoid processing Logs that have no changes
    Dim FDate As Date = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(sSqlLogPathFile)
    If FDate.ToString = lblSQLLOGS_Saved.Text Then Exit Sub ' log have no changes > exit
    lblSQLLOGS_Saved.Text = FDate.ToString

    ' Read SQL LOG
    Dim fs As New FileStream(sSqlLogPathFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(fs)
    Dim sLogText As String = sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Close()
    fs.Close()

    ' Start Processing
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear
    Dim bOneOrMoreIPStoBlock As Boolean = False
    Dim iCountSameIP, k As Integer
    Dim sLine, sIP As String
    Dim iNewLoginFailed As Integer
    Dim iLine As Integer = 0
    Dim iStart As Integer = 1
    Do
        iNewLoginFailed = InStr(iStart, sLogText, "Login failed for user")
        If iNewLoginFailed > 0 Then
            sLine = Mid(sLogText, iNewLoginFailed, InStr(iNewLoginFailed, sLogText, "]") - iNewLoginFailed + 1)
            sIP = Mid(sLine.Replace("]", ""), InStr(sLine, "[CLIENT: ") + Len("[CLIENT: "), 100)
            iStart = iNewLoginFailed

            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            DataGridView1.Rows(iLine).Cells("xText").Value = sLine
            DataGridView1.Rows(iLine).Cells("xIp").Value = sIP

            ' We don't want to block 10 times the same IP, here we choose 3 failed logins for the same ip to block it just once
            ' You can put this section after the Loop While but you'll need it if you want to block the ip right away
            iCountSameIP = 0
            For k = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                If DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("xIp").Value.ToString = sIP Then iCountSameIP += 1
            Next
            DataGridView1.Rows(iLine).Cells("xSameIP").Value = iCountSameIP
            If iCountSameIP = 3 Then ' 3 failed (same ip) = block, you can change to 1
                DataGridView1.Rows(iLine).Cells("xAction").Value = "BLOCK"
                bOneOrMoreIPStoBlock = True
                ' you can block the IP at this point, in this example we do it later
                ' just get the ip from the var sIP
            End If
        End If

        iLine += 1
    Loop While iNewLoginFailed > 0 AndAlso iLine <= 5000

    If bOneOrMoreIPStoBlock Then
        For k = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("xAction").Value = "BLOCK" Then
                ' BLOCK THIS IP
                sIP = DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("xIp").Value.ToString)
                MsgBox("BLOCK IP: " & DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("xIp").Value.ToString)

                ' I use this next lines to block the IP, just uncomment it in production mode

                'Dim sProcess As String = "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""BlockIP_" & sIP _
                '& """ dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=" & sIP & "/32"
                'Shell(sProcess, AppWinStyle.Hide)

            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```